# Running Ubuntu Even With XP Installed

Tags: software-installation

I am brand new to using this type of an OS. I currently am running XP, and am wondering when I boot my PC, do I have the option of choosing to run Ubuntu instead of XP? Further, with XP being fazed in favor of Windows 8, how will Ubuntu hold up in terms of anti-virus protection? I am aware that with XP being fazed out, security updates will no longer be available.

Answer (score 0):

you can install ubuntu along with your existing operating system.. no issues in that, as far as your doubt is concerned you will definitely get an option to choose when you are booting your PC and coming to to anti virus protection you no need to install any anti-virus software the operating system it self will take care of it.
for installation steps please refer [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation).

and if you want to run ubuntu along with your windows please refer to [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows).

Hope this helps.